# Err: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in Jupyter notebook when executing a file

Tags: python

I just switched to python 3 from python 2.5 and I had a code that worked in 2.5 that I ran from the jupyter notebook like so:

```
execfile('IRDCGrouper.py')
```

but now I'm trying this:

```
exec(open('IRDCGrouper.py').read())
```

Some of my other more simple programs are able to execute, but this one comes with the error:

```
<ipython-input-5-494d757df0a7> in <module>()
----> 1 exec(open("IRDCGrouper.py").read())
<string> in <module>()
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I've seen many other questions with the same error, but everyone else seemed to have the error point to a line of their code, it's certainly possible that there something in my code that isn't compatible with python 3, but if that was true, wouldn't it point to the place in the code where it failed? I'm not quite sure where to start to look. 
Thanks!

Edit:
I get the same error when I just try to run the following:

`f = open('testfile.reg', 'wb')`

`f.write('box    (    %f    ,    %f    ,    '%(10,20))
f.write('%f"    ,    %f"    ,    0)    #    %f\n'%(15,25,35))`

Comment: I got the same error. I also tried with replacing 'rb' with 'r'.

Comment: can you share the contents of your script?

Comment: It's pretty long, I'm not sure what the best way to show you is, but some problem areas could be from when it reads in or writes out text files and .py files. Would putting up the part of the script that does that be helpful?

Comment: okay, can you try with a small script and see if it works. If it doesn't then you have a [mcve] to share with us :)

Comment: I added a very simple example in my question. If this is the error, then is there a way in the new python for it to point out where it fails when it tries to run the file? In python 2.X I found it very helpful for it to point out where if failed and what the error was.

Comment: I fixed the error, I just needed to replace 'wb' with 'w'. (New to stack exchange, should I edit my original question with the solution?)

Comment: your example is the issue: try `f = open('testfile.reg', 'w')`. OK you found that yourself. That's the virtue of the [mcve] I asked for :) Well, you can answer your own question, but you have to make it useful for the others, otherwise it's just as well to delete your question.